# is it possible to override sencha touch carousel previous and next functions?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, carousel

I am using sencha touch to develop mobile website.

```
Ext.setup( {
    onReady: function() {

      new Ext.Carousel({
        fullscreen: true,
        items: [
          {
            html: "Item1"
},
{ 
  html : "Item2"
}
]});};});
```

is what i use. But is it possible to override next() and prev() functions. Actually i want to do something inside those function and then call parent.next() i mean same function .
Any help??
I saw the link http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?110036-Override-Method 
But i cant understand that

Answer (score 1):

Refer this code for your requirement.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('MyApp.view.inbox.MyInbox', {
            extend: 'Ext.Carousel',
            config: {
                itemId:'test',
                fullscreen: true,
                items: [{
                    html: "Item1"
                },{ 
                    html : "Item2"
                }]
            },
            next:function(){
                //Do your thing

                //This code will call the next in the super class
                this.callParent(arguments);
            },
            prev:function(){
                //Do your thing

                //This code will call the prev in the super class
                this.callParent(arguments);
            }
        });
        Ext.create('MyApp.view.inbox.MyInbox');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks . I tried this code but it is not entering inside next and prev functions at all.It is directly going to main next and prev functions i guess

Comment: ok that works fine,But in my case i dont want to add any extra buttons.I want to override next and prev functions without adding any extra buttons

Comment: The buttons was just to show that which function gets called. If you call next() of the carousel object, our classes 'next' gets called. I think you are referring about swiping in the carousel?